Pausing the VBA code till Query refresh is complete
ok
so i created a Query to pull data in from an external excel sheet and transform it to how i need it.
columns A-Y are from this data then i added columns AA-DP so i can manually input data.
i used VBA to made 2 buttons one to copy and paste all of the current worksheet to another worksheet then clear the data and refresh with updated data.
Second button is a look up , it looks at the copied data (data bk up) and returns the manual values back to columns AA - DP.
and this works fine but i was asked to combined them and have it all work under 1 button.
problem i have now is even though i have them in the right order the copy and pasting then look up happens before the query has updated. which means the return values are already there before query has new load data. so it won't match up if new data is loaded in.
i've tried all sorts of way to make the code waiting till the refresh has completed but they don't work.
also i have been in to the options and unticked enable background refresh which help speed the query up but didnt solve my problem.
Sub MasterSubroutine()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Call the CopyPaste subroutine
    CopyPaste
    
    ' Call the Lookup subroutine
    Lookup
    
    ' Notify user that all operations have been completed
    MsgBox "Data copied, backup created, queries refreshed, and lookup completed.", vbInformation
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsBackup As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    
    ' Set references to worksheets
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set wsBackup = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Bk Up")
    
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    ' Clear contents of backup sheet
    wsBackup.Cells.Clear
    
    ' Copy data from source to backup sheet
    wsSource.UsedRange.Copy
    wsBackup.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    ' Clear specific ranges in source sheet
    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow >= 2 Then
        wsSource.Range("AA2:DP" & lastRow).ClearContents
    End If
    
    ' Adjust row height and column widths (if needed)
    wsSource.Rows(1).RowHeight = 65
    wsSource.Range("A1:DP1").WrapText = True
    wsSource.Range("B:C, E:F, I:DP").ColumnWidth = 10
    wsSource.Range("G:I").ColumnWidth = 17
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred in CopyPaste: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub WaitForDataRefresh()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Do
        Dim isRefreshing As Boolean
        isRefreshing = False
        For Each qt In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").QueryTables
            If qt.refreshing Then
                isRefreshing = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next qt
        If Not isRefreshing Then Exit Do
        DoEvents
    Loop
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub

   

Sub Lookup()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim lookupValue1 As Variant
    Dim lookupValue2 As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim found As Boolean
    
    ' Set references to the worksheets
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    Set ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Bk Up")
    
    ' Get the last rows for the loops
    Dim lastRow1 As Long
    Dim lastRow2 As Long
    lastRow1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow2 = ws4.Cells(ws4.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each row in Sheet1
    For i = 2 To lastRow1
        ' Get the lookup values from cells B and C in Sheet1
        lookupValue1 = ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        lookupValue2 = ws1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        
        ' Reset found flag for each iteration
        found = False
        
        ' Loop through each row in Sheet4 to perform the lookup
        For j = 1 To lastRow2
            ' Check if current row matches lookup values
            If ws4.Cells(j, 2).Value = lookupValue1 And ws4.Cells(j, 3).Value = lookupValue2 Then
                ' If match found, assign the return values to Sheet1 columns AA to DP
                ws1.Cells(i, 27).Resize(, 86).Value = ws4.Cells(j, 27).Resize(, 86).Value
                found = True
                Exit For ' Exit loop once match is found
            End If
        Next j
        
        ' Check if no match was found and assign 0 to Sheet1 columns AA to DP
        If Not found Then
            ws1.Cells(i, 27).Resize(, 86).Value = ""
        End If
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred in Lookup: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End Sub


Right-click all the queries in the workbook, change the query properties to uncheck “Enable Background Refresh”


i did put in my comments i have already done this
